# Creating a Search button with regex

Tags: c#, regex, search

So I'm basically trying to create a search button.

This search is using REGEX.

I think I have it correct but it's not working, Can someone tell me how / where i've gone wrong, Not coded in AGES...

```
    public void SearchFunction(string searchtext)
    {
        SupporterId();
        ReferenceNumber();
        ConsignmentNumber();
    }
    private static void SupporterId()
    {
        const string sId= "";
        var supporterId = Regex.IsMatch(sId, @"^[A-F,S,R][0-9]{3,6}$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    }

    private static void ReferenceNumber()
    {
        const string refNumber = "";
        var referenceNumber = Regex.IsMatch(refNumber, @"^[ABN158][0-9]{6,17}$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    }

    private static void ConsignmentNumber()
    {
        const string conNumber = "";
        var consignmentNumber = Regex.IsMatch(conNumber, @"&[0-9]{14}$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        }
    }
}
```

Those are my Regex, And this is my code behind..

```
    protected void CheckStateClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        ConsignmentSearch();
    }

    private void ConsignmentSearch()
    {
        var searchclass = new RegexMethods();
        searchclass.SearchFunction(txtReferenceNumber.Text);
    }
```

Can anyone tell me where I have gone wrong and HOW I can fix it, Please don't tell me oh your missing this an then don't tell me how to fix it.

IF you can tell me how / what needs adding to be fixed example: add this line of code here .... <  >

Please and thank you.

__
THIS IS THE ERROR
Test 'M:DeliveryInputSystem.Default.AddBox_Click(System.Object,System.EventArgs)' failed: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
    System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
    Default.aspx.cs(113,0): at DeliveryInputSystem.Default.AddBox_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)

Comment: You haven't even said what your issue is, "Not working" is far too vague

Answer (score 0):

I may be wrong, but it looks like you are only checking empty strings...
How about checking your searchtext like this:

```
public void SearchFunction(string searchtext)
{
    SupporterId(searchtext);
    ReferenceNumber(searchtext);
    ConsignmentNumber(searchtext);
}
private static void SupporterId(string sId)
{
    var supporterId = Regex.IsMatch(sId, @"^[A-F,S,R][0-9]{3,6}$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
}

private static void ReferenceNumber(string refNumber)
{
    var referenceNumber = Regex.IsMatch(refNumber, @"^[ABN158][0-9]{6,17}$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
}

private static void ConsignmentNumber(string conNumber)
{
    var consignmentNumber = Regex.IsMatch(conNumber, @"&[0-9]{14}$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);  
}
```

However, if I understand your code correctly, your searchtext variable only contains the txtReferenceNumber.Text text, so you should only run the ReferenceNumber(string searchtext) method on it.

Comment: I tried this method, I wrote what you put but it doesn't work still.

Comment: Below I have included 2 screen shots so you can see what I see. http://prntscr.com/36v0kf - http://prntscr.com/36v0o0

Comment: What is the problem? No one can help if we don't actually know what the problem is. As far as I can see, the null reference exception you have posted in your question isn't related to the Regex code you have posted.

Answer (score 0):

You provided error text:

```
__ THIS IS THE ERROR Test' 
M:DeliveryInputSystem.Default.AddBox_Click(System.Object,System.EventArgs)' failed:
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
System.NullReferenceException:
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
Default.aspx.cs(113,0): at DeliveryInputSystem.Default.AddBox_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
```

There is written cause of error: `NullReferenceException` and where does it occur `Default.aspx.cs(113,0)`. You need to analyze what is there, in line `113` in `Default.aspx.cs` and why may it cause `NullReferenceException`.

If you don't know where to start, start with documentation. According to [MSDN documentation for NullReferenceException class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/system.nullreferenceexception%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> A NullReferenceException exception is thrown when you try to access a member on a type whose value is null.

You have often also an example there:

```
1:  List<String> names;
2:  if (sth) names = new List<String>();
3:  names.Add("Major Major Major")
```

If `sth` is `false` then no instance is assigned to `names` and exception will be thrown.

Comment: I just don't understand what It means by " Object reference not set to an instance of an object "

Comment: @PkinJ0r that's why you should expect getting hints how to do it by yourself. I edited answer with information, what `NullReferenceException` is.

Comment: Thank you for the tip, But I don't understand what Object reference not set to an instance of an object, What I'm trying to do is call from my classes * The regex *, So it can find the ID

Comment: In the .text box - and then search using a stored protocol in the SQL

Comment: @PkinJ0r Read whole page of documentation I provided. You have it all described there. `Object reference not set to an instance of an object` is description of `NullReferenceException`.